# Relation between $\dim\ker(T - \lambda I)$ and number of Jordan Block's

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $T : V \to V$ be an endomorphism. Why is $\dim \ker(T - \lambda \cdot I)$ the number of jordan block's correspoding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there is *exactly* one (linearly independent) eigenvector per Jordan block, and that $\dim \ker (T - \lambda I)$ is *exactly* the number of linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: this just gives an upper bound...

Comment: It's a lower bound, too. There is **exactly** one linearly independent eigenvector per Jordan block

Comment: you mean there is a 1-1 correspondence between lineary independent eigenvectors and jordan blocks's.

Comment: That is indeed another way to say what I said